# Firebase storage query if an image file exists

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For each unique userID there may or may not be a directory in the Firebase storage containing an image named **profile.jpg**.
I'm trying to create a query that will sort all the users:

1. With `"age": 12` and
2. Have a **profile.jpg** file in the storage under the directory named after their userId.

My database structure is:

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "uid1" : {
      "name" : "Josh",
      "age": 12
    },
    "uid2" : {
      "name" : "June",
      "age": 13
    }
  }
}
```

And my Storage structure is like:

```
example.appspot.com > uploads > uid1 > profile.jpg
```

I have managed to solve the first section that sorts the users with age 12 with the following:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").orderByChild("age").equalTo(12);
```

But how can I also add the second logic that is, at first after sorting the users aged 12, filter them who have a profile image in the same query.

Comment: Are you asking if you can sort by one field *and* filter by a second field in the same query?

Comment: Yes, first sort the users aged 12, then filter them who have a profile image in the same query. @DougStevenson

Comment: `if they who have a profile image in the same query` there is not any node contains profileImage in the json output so, how would you expect to filter them? At least, if there was, we could do magic maybe..

Comment: Yes, that's my point. I don't have a node in the json but is it possible to have a look at the Storage if such file exists and sort them who have? @ʍѳђઽ૯ท

Comment: You may wanna consider adding a `profileImage` node first then checking if the user has the `imgProfile` or not. However, when it does not even have a node, why would you check anything? Sorry, sounds ridiculous ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible to combine a FirebaseDatabase query with a Firebase Storage query.  I would recommend adding a node to your database, that says whether or not the user has a profile.jpg or not, and then choose which field you want to sort on.

```
 {
  "Users" : {
    "uid1" : {
      "name" : "Josh",
      "age": 12,
      "hasPhoto": true
    },
    "uid2" : {
      "name" : "June",
      "age": 13,
      "hasPhoto": false
    }
  }
}
```

Then, I think that Firebase Realtime Database does not allow sorting on more than one field, so instead you could do this:

Sort on one field ("age"), get the result, and then sort/filter through those User objects client side based on whether they have jpg or not.  Alternatively, Firestore does allow querying on more than one field.